# why i can use jpa 2 feature Criteria API in JDeveloper and Weblogic!

Tags: jpa-2.0, weblogic11g

I'm writing criteria API  but not work with Weblogic Server. I find that (jpa1.x.x.jar,jpa2.x.x.jar) Library file in weblogic module folder.

I am calling EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
But It shows syntax error, I think it doesn't know the library file.

The EntityManager is included in  both jpa1.x.x.jar and jpa2.x.x.jar, 
but getCriteriaBuilder() is only included in jpa2.x.x.jar file.

I think it should work because the required library is included.

The version I used is JDeveloper 11.1.14 and Integrated Weblogic.

-waiting for your reply.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Do you have a stack trace?  If so, update your question with it please.

Answer (score 1):

I completed my question with NetBean IDE 7.0. In netbean version 7, I can enable/disable jpa2.0 and jsf2.0 with Weblogic 10.3.